# Set a fixed controller/action for extension/plugin which are not influenced by whatever is passed on the query string

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I want to bootstrap/embed an extension with fixed controller/action and no matter what is passed to the query string (e.g. tx_*[controller]/tx_*[action]) should not change the behavior of the embedded/bootstrapped version of the extension.

Basically I need to insert multiple instances of the same extension/plugin and each instance should only call what I have defined. Currently it throws an exception if it's not allowed or if I allow it it executes whatever is in the query string.

I want to be able to do that with the same plugin with different controllers.

Is it possible?

EDIT:

Lets say I have a plugin with 3 controllers - List, Show, Top. I want to embed in my page the controllers List and Top. When I click on details in List in my query string I have the appropriate arguments so the extension knows I want to show details on one of the items in list. But these arguments also influence what is shown in Top and now Top shows the same thing as List. I want to be able to embed the Top controller who will never change its output based on the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do it the same way - and failed to do it in a clean way.
According to several tickets on the forge it is recommended to split it up in different plugins.

/edit: 
Just as an additional reference, you could check config.tx_extbase.mvc.callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved = 1

Perhaps it can help you in your case.

Comment: callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved did the trick but I don't think it's an elegant solution. I've posted the same question in forge, lets hope they do something about it. Thank you.